# Magento SOAP API "Customer address is not set." error

Tags: api, magento, soap

I got the following error

"Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1054] Internal Error." when calling "cart_customer.addresses" function via the SOAP API.

Below is my code

```
    $s_arrAddresses = array(
            array(
                "mode" => "shipping",
                "address_id" => "14",
                "country_id" => "AE",
                "city" => "Dubai City"
            )
     );

     $resultCustomerAddresses = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_customer.addresses", array($shoppingCartId, $s_arrAddresses));
```

May I know what parameters did i miss out or I have enter wrong information in which parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may find solution [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartCustomer/cart_customer.addresses.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is due to some error in Magento Core library. I managed to find the error in error.log and solved it.

Comment: For completeness, and to help anyone else who may encounter the same issue in the future, it would be useful to explain what the error was and how you fixed it.